# Get actual length of the defined String in Java

Tags: java, string

I've defined String as

```
String s = "\\";
int length = s.length(); // returns 1
System.out.println(s); // prints only one "\"
```

How can I get it's size equal to `2` ?

**UPD:** The problem is not in getting exactly 2-sized String. I need to get the count of source characters which I've defined my String by.

Comment: Did you try printing the String.. Just to ensure that your understanding is correct?

Comment: @SeniorJD please listen to what several people are telling you: 1 **is** the length of the string you have defined.

Comment: It might be worth stating exactly why you need to know the length is two instead of one - does your program need to know specifically if Strings are being escaped?

Comment: @SeniorJD, I think you are trying to solve an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It is also worth noting that there is no way to distinguish between a String literal defined as `"\\"` and a String literal defined as `"\u005c"`, since they both represent the same String; however, they are of different lengths in the source code.

Comment: @AndyTurner that's what I'm asking about. So, there is no way to get the count of characters which I've defined String by?

Comment: They are *exactly* the same string. Totally indistinguishable. The only way you can do this is by parsing the source code.

Comment: By the way, if the difference between backslash-escaped and octal-escaped strings is what you are really asking about, you should make that clear in your question, because it isn't obvious.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm sorry, can you help me with this please? English is far not my native language. I've tried to make it more clear in UPD section.

Comment: "`String s1 = "\\"; String s2 = "\u005c"; System.out.println(s1.length() == s2.length());` Why are these the same length? How can I tell that they are declared differently?"

Comment: @AndyTurner hmm for me it is not clear too because it also seems like I don't know about escaping characters, isn't it?

Comment: you make a confusion between your code source in java (length 2) and your code for runtime (length 1). => if you want 2, you have to parse your code, with a method or other. See answer of ArcticLord for example. But why do you want that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CharConverter from [DrJava](http://www.drjava.org/). You could adapt the [source code](http://drjava.org/javadoc/javalanglevels/src-html/edu/rice/cs/javalanglevels/CharConverter.html) for your project. It has a method that converts all the escaped chars in a string back to the real Java input.

```
String str1 = "\\";
String str2 = CharConverter.escapeString(str1);
System.out.println(str2.length());   // prints 2
```

Answer (score 10):

`String s = "\\";` contains only the character `\`, and since it is a *special one*, it has to be escaped with the `\` character.

In order to obtain a 2-sized String, you can escape two backslashes, like this:

```
String s = "\\\\";
```

This one doesn't have the size of `4`, but `2`, because there are characters (obviously, like the backslash) which are not represented by a single visual element in the editor.

There are also characters, which can be completely invisible when being printed (like the [Mongolian vowel separator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/180e/index.htm)), but which are represented in a different way in the source (by their Unicode code). For example, the Mongolian vowel separator can be represented as:

```
String mongolianVowelSeparator = "\u180"; <-- one character only, invisible when printed
```

So here we have one character only (the `U+180E` Unicode character), but we used five editor characters to represent it.

Comment: But, in this case I need to get `4` as answer

Comment: No, you should understand that some characters are represented in the code as a sequence of characters.

Comment: @SeniorJD - No, you wont.. `\\` has special meaning in java. It is considered as *escape character*

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I think you need to escape your escape character... ;)

Comment: @AndyTurner - Lol.. It was invisible to *Andy Turner's* eyes :P

Comment: @SeniorJD as you said u r new to java...  once go through "escape sequence" topic in java

Comment: @AshwaniKumarRahul where have I said I'm a newbie?

Answer (score 2):

See the [JLS - 3.10.6. Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6):

> The character and string escape sequences allow for the representation of some nongraphic characters as well as the single quote, double quote, and **backslash** characters in character literals ([§3.10.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4)) and string literals ([§3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)).
>
> ...
>
> `\ \           /* \u005c: backslash \ */`

The character `\` is used in [Unicode Escapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3):

> In addition to the processing implied by the grammar, for each raw input character that **is a backslash `\`**, input processing must consider how many other `\` characters contiguously precede it, separating it from a non-`\` character or the start of the input stream. If this number is even, then the `\` is eligible to begin a Unicode escape; if the number is odd, then the `\` is not eligible to begin a Unicode escape.

It's worth mentioning that your string can be written as:

```
\u005c
```

Since `005c` is the *Unicode value* for `\`.

Answer (score -2):

As stated above, "\" is an escape character and does not add up to string's total length. However, if you insist that escape characters be added to total length, try this piece of code below.

For every "\" in your strings increments total length by one.

```
String s = "\\";
int length = s.length();

for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
   if(s.charAt(i) == '\')
      length++;
```

Comment: I suggest you you use your logic sometimes. Anyway, just change the code a bit:
for(int i = 1; i < s.length; i++)
   if(s.charAt(i - 1) == '\' && s.charAt(i) == '\')
      length++;

Comment: what if String is `"123\123"` ?

Comment: Please re-phrase your request. I can hardly understand you.