# Java - String.lastIndexOf(str) logic I cannot understand

Tags: java, string, indexing, lastindexof

I used two different string to test the last index of "\t", but they both return 4. I thought it should be 5 and 4. I checked the oracle docs and I could not understand why. Could someone please tell me why? Thank you!

```
System.out.println("abc\t\tsubdir".lastIndexOf("\t"));
System.out.println("abct\tsubdir".lastIndexOf("\t"));
```

Comment: Are you confused by the length of `\t`? That's a String literal, its length at runtime will be one, a character representing a tab. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393312/get-actual-length-of-the-defined-string-in-java

Answer (score 10):

Lets make the number of indexes to understand it better :

String 1

```
a b c \t \t s u b d i r
0 1 2  3  4 5 6 7 8 9 10
          ^-----------------------------------last index of \t (for that you get 4)
```

String 2

```
a b c t \t s u b d i r
0 1 2 3  4 5 6 7 8 9 10
         ^-----------------------------------last index of \t (for that you get 4)
```

---

There are some special characters that should be escaped by `\` (tab `\t`, breadline `\n`, quote `\"` ...) In Java, so it count as one character and not 2

Answer (score 4):

In the first line, the last tab is at 4
`a b c <tab> <tab>`

In the second line, the last tab is at 4 also
`a b c t <tab>`

`\t` counts as 1 character

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `\t` does not count as two characters, it is an escape sequence and counts for only one character.

You can find the full list of escape sequences here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that the count starts from zero and '\t' only counts as one character. This can be confusing at times especially if you forget to start form zero.

```
0|1|2| 3| 4
a|b|c|\t|\t
a|b|c| t|\t
```

Comment: This answer did not exist when I started typing my answer and I have edited mine to reflect it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The count start with zero in java, that the reason why first and sysout returns 4. for your better understanding i added 3rd sysout where you can find the last index of \t will returns zero.

```
/**
 * @author itsection
 */
public class LastIndexOf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("abc\t\tsubdir".lastIndexOf("\t"));
        System.out.println("abct\tsubdir".lastIndexOf("\t"));
        System.out.println("\tabctsubdir".lastIndexOf("\t"));
    }
}// the output will be 4,4,0
```